# Using modelstate.isvalid to validate data from inside the controller in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am pretty new to ASP.NET MVC3 but i have about 4 years of experience with PHP frameworks.

I am trying to build an MVC3 web app, but i am having issues with validationg my model.
Here is a test controller to show you what i am trying without success to do.

I am trying to pass a value to my model inside the controller, but it doesnt take it into account the parameter.

I tried using modelstate.setmodelvalue, for junk.sentence, but it keeps the value from the POST request which is invalid an that i want to change by default (for test purposes) in the controller.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Michael

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Junk junk)
    {
        //ModelState.Clear();
        junk.sentence = "coucou";

        ModelState.SetModelValue("sentence", new ValueProviderResult(junk.sentence, junk.number, null));


        //ModelState
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Junks.Add(junk);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(junk);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Junk/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Junk junk = db.Junks.Find(id);
        return View(junk);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing it from modelstate:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Junk junk)
{
    junk.sentence = "coucou";

    //ModelState
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Junks.Add(junk);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    ModelState.Remove("sentence");
    return View(junk);
}
```

This assumes that in your view you have a corresponding input field that was generated using some of the Html helpers such as EditorFor for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.sentence)
```

or:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.sentence)
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that it doesnt validate "sentence" anymore because right now it is a constant string, but later i want to put variables... which i will want to validate. but thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MichaelCh, oops, indeed. I have updated my answer and moved the `ModelState.Remove` at the end of the action just prior to returning the view.

Comment: there is still a problem in that case, because now modelstate.isvalid doesnt take into account the new value of the "junk" model...
I cant have an html helper in my view because i have a many to many relationship, so i use checkboxes that i will get from the formcollection...

Comment: @MichaelCh, the validation is performed by the default model binder before calling the actual method body. So the ModelState.IsValid property value will depend on whether this default model binder stored some errors in it. If you remove the value before calling IsValid your model will now be valid which is normal, and if you remove it after, it will still use the old value which is normal. You cannot modify the value like that for validation.

Answer (score 0):

ModelState.IsValid returns false when there are model errors added to the model state. MVC validates the properties on your model and creates a list of errors for you in the ModelState. You must remove the errors from the model state that you wish to be ignored from inside your controller action. You can then update the actual values on the model. (Darin Dimitrov shows you an example of doing this)